# click event for dynamic content not triggering in first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to implement keyword search in my site. And search result contains an anchor to get the detailed view. And it shows a popup in the click event of anchor. But my problem is, this popup do not render in first click. If I again click the link the popup will come. I am here pasting a screen shot of my search window and my script. Someone please help me to rectify this issue.

[image]

**Script :**

```js
function showAdvancedSearch(value) {

  var searchResults = '<div class="scrollbar-inner">';
  var status = "";
  var color = "";
  $.ajax({
    url: base_url + 'Panel/quickSearch',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      q: value
    },
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {
      result = $.parseJSON(result);

      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

        if (result[i]['TargetedUserHolded'] == 'Y') {
          status = 'Hold';
          color = 'yellow';
        } else if (result[i]['MeetingExecuted'] == 'Y') {
          status = 'Completed';
          color = 'green';
        } else if (result[i]['MeetingCancelled'] == 'Y') {
          status = 'Cancelled';
          color = 'blue';
        } else {
          color = 'blue';
        }
        var d = new Date(result[i]['MeetingStartDateTime']);
        var amOrPm = (d.getHours() < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";
        var hour = (d.getHours() < 12) ? d.getHours() : d.getHours() - 12;
        var minutes = d.getMinutes();
        var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = d.getDate();
        var year = d.getFullYear();

        searchResults += '<div class="board-details ' + color + '">' +
          '<div class="board-head">' +
          result[i]['FirstName'] + ' Scheduled Meeting <em>(' + status + ')</em>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<p>' + result[i]['MeetingNote'] + '.</p>' +
          '<div class="board-flex">' +
          '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="view-details"  data-meeting-id="' + result[i]['MeetingID'] + '">view details</a>' +
          '<span class="time">' + day + '-' + month + '-' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + ' ' + amOrPm + '</span>';
        if (status == 'Hold') {
          searchResults += '<div class="pull-right">' +
            '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="action accept" title="Accept"></a>' +
            '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="action reject" title="Reject"></a> ' +
            '</div>';
        }
        searchResults += '</div>' +
          '</div>';
      }
    }
  });
  searchResults += '</div>' +
    '<a href="' + base_url + 'advanced-search" class="advanced">advanced search</a>';

  $('.search-inner').html(searchResults);





  TweenLite.set($('#quick-search').parent().find('.search-inner'), {
    display: 'block'
  });
}
$(document).on('click', 'a.view-details', function() {
    alert(1);    
});
```

This issue is happening only for dynamically added content. Because I tried to trigger this same view details event in another section(contents loaded in page load) and its working fine.

**UPDATE**
I removed some code for easy understanding. The alert function is not working in first click, because the event is not triggering in first click

Comment: Aside from the issue you describe, remove `async: false`. It's incredibly bad practice, to the point the browser will show warnings in the console telling you not to do it. Use the callback pattern properly instead

Comment: And delegation in place: `$(document).on('click', 'a.view-details', function() {`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ok. I removed this from my code

Comment: But why is `function defaultPopup(part) {` inside the click function?

Comment: @mplungjan defaultPopup(part) is not defined inside the click event. I am just calling that function from click event

Comment: The function looks to be inside now we clicked “tidy” on the code. It likely should not be inside

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do:

1. Add the click event handler after you create the element
2. pass a onclick function into your view-details which then handles the click

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

try document click in document.ready

i hope it works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on('click', 'a.view-details', function() {
     //your code
     });
});
```

or you can try rebinding the click event at the end of showAdvancedSearch() function like this

```
$("a.view-details").bind("click", function(){
    alert("anchor is clicked");
});
```

Comment: still the same :(

Comment: Can you see anything in console?